# nodejs calling database calls parallel

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

The module calls three tables(students, subjects, grades)I call three sql queries and somehow managed to call one by one as explained below. the queries are independent of each other. However the select queries are executed one by one, first student, then subjects, then grades using await.

studentmodel.calls are only for executing select quesries from the database and is in one module. Other functions are defined in a separate module

The logic can execute the three selct queries(database calls) in parallel, then aggregate and process all the data together. Please let me know how to modify so that the database calls can execute independent, then move to process all data together

processing module -main start call

```
const mainstart = async () => {
    let students = 0;

    const getStudentData = await getAllStudents();

    /** checking a condition if getEmployeeData responce is not empty */
    if (getStudentData.length > 0) {
        const studentData = await processData(getStudentData);
        return 1;

    } else {
        return 0;
    }
};



same file secondcall to the function getAllStudents

const getAllStudents = async () => {
    try {
        return await studentmodel.getAllStudents();//database call 1
    } catch (err) {
        // console.log("processing", err)
    }
};




const processData = async (getStudentData) => {
    try {

        let studentData = [];

        const subjectsData = await studentModel.getStudentSubjects();//database call 2

        const gradesData = await studentModel.getStudentGrades();//database call 3

        await Promise.all(getStudentData.map(async (singleObject) => {

            let subjects = await processSubjects(subjectsData, singleObject.student_log);
            let grades = await processGrades(gradesData, singleObject.student_log);  

        //Some processing on sigleobject, subjects and grades to populate studentData array
          
        }));
        return studentData;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("processing", err)
    }
};

const processSubjects = async (result, Name) => {
    let subjectsArr = [];

    const processArray = result.filter(ele => ele.student_log == Name)

    processArray.map((singleObject) => {
        subjectsArr.push({
            name: singleObject.name,
            startDate: singleObject.startDate,
        });
    })
    return subjectsArr;
}

const processGrades = async (result, Name) => {
    let gradesArr = [];
    const processArray = result.filter(ele => ele.student_log == Name)
    processArray.map((singleObject) => {
        gradesArr.push({
            id: singleObject.id,
            name: singleObject.name,
        });
    })
    return gradesArr;
```

database calls module/studentModel

```
const getAllStudents = async () => {
    try {

        /** Populating all students */
        const sqlQuery = `SELECT * FROM STUDENTS`;

        let [result] = await bigQuery.query({
            query: sqlQuery,
            location: 'US'
        });


        return result;

    } catch (err) {
        return false;
    }

};

const getStudentSubjects = async () => {
    try {

        /** Populating all skills */
        const sqlQuery = `SELECT * FROM Subjects`;

        let [result] = await bigQuery.query({
            query: sqlQuery,
            location: 'US'
        });


        return result;

    } catch (err) {
        return false;
    }

};
const getStudentGrades = async () => {
    try {

        /** Populating all students */
        const sqlQuery = `SELECT * FROM GRADES`;

        let [result] = await bigQuery.query({
            query: sqlQuery,
            location: 'US'
        });


        return result;

    } catch (err) {
        return false;
    }

};
```

Comment: Which functions do you want to execute in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I didn't probably fully understand what your question is, I had a go with your code.

I simulated your studentmodel functions with `setTimeout` and made the code like so that it first fetches all students. After fetching all students, it fetches the subjects and the grades "in parallel" by utilising `Promise.all`. After we have fetched our students, subjects and grades, we pass all of those to `processData` function where you can process all of the data however you want.

In case you would also like to fetch the students "in parallel" with the subjects and grades, just change the `Promise.all` part like so:

```
const [studentData, studentSubjects, studentGrades] = await Promise.all(
[
    getAllStudents(),
    getStudentSubjects(), 
    getStudentGrades()
]);
```

And remove the `const studentData = await getAllStudents();` line and the if-clause. Because you had the `if(studentData.length > 0)` in your code, I assumed that we only want to fetch subjects and grades if there are students and therefore that needs to be done first, separately.

Note that if you want to do all three in parallel, you cannot use studentData when calling `getStudentSubjects` or `getStudentGrades`.

```js
// STUDENTMODEL

const getAllStudents = async () => {
    // Simulate SQL query
    console.log("Fetching students");
    return new Promise(resolve => 
      setTimeout(() => { 
      resolve(["Student 1", "Student 2"]) 
      }, 1000));
};

const getStudentSubjects = async () => {
    // Simulate SQL query
    console.log("Fetching subjects");
    return new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(["Subject 1", "Subject 2"])
      }, 1500));
};

const getStudentGrades = async () => {
    // Simulate SQL query
    console.log("Fetching grades");
    return new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(["Grade 1", "Grade 2"])
      }, 1500));
};


const mainstart = async () => {
    // Fetch student data from database
    const studentData = await getAllStudents();

    if (studentData.length > 0) {
        // Use Promise.all to wait until both student subjects and
        // student grades have been fetched
        // The results are destructured into
        // studentSubjects and studentGrades variables
        const [studentSubjects, studentGrades] = await Promise.all(
        [
          getStudentSubjects(studentData), 
          getStudentGrades(studentData)
        ]); 
        
        // Everything is fetched, process it all
        processData([studentData, studentSubjects, studentGrades]);
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
};

const processData = (allData) => {
    console.log("Processing all data");
    console.log(allData);
    
    // Process data somehow
};

(async () => {
  console.log('start');
  await mainstart(); 
  console.log('end');
})();
```

Comment: Thanks. so allData[0] will have the studentdata? I can call await Promise.all(allData[0].map(async (singleObject)... I will test this. Yes this is what I want

Comment: You don't need any awaits, promises or async inside the processData-function. When the program gets there, everything asynchronous such as database fetches are already done (and map is not inherently asynchronous or the function passed to it) But yeah, allData[0] has studentdata.